# Pathfinder in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a sort of javascript game and I basically have a bunch of tiles (divs) generated by a little script. I know the basics of pathfinding and how to work with my tiles and such.

But, what I'm having a bit of trouble with is in someway storing these tiles so I can pick out the 8 surronding ones fromthe tile I'm on.

So basicly, let's say I'm standing a on a tile

(E-tiles, T-tile I'm on, B-Tile I want to go to)

E E E E E E

E T E E E B

E E E E E E

Now I want to "find" the tiles around me, which I need help/tips on how to do, (that will say, I need tips on how to store the tiles so I can "browse" them later".

I want to find these without problems;

(E-tiles, T-tile I'm on, B-Tile I want to go to, Y-What I want to find)

Y Y Y E E E

Y T Y E E B

Y Y Y E E E

Also a little bonus would be on how to store these so I know for example; I pick a tile from the selected "Y" tiles, and I run through them and finally pick the one that makes me closer to "B".

Any tips/tricks/help is much appriciated!

Comment: Can you always move to any tile next to you, or will some tiles be blocked so you need to go around?

Comment: Well, eventually there will be walls, but and there wont be tiles "behind" the walls, so I guess yes and no. So, every tile that you can "find" you can go to.

But like I said, I can manage the pathfinding later, just that I need smart way to store the tiles.

Answer (score 0):

You could store your world as an array of arrays of tiles, with the indices representing x/y coordinates.

```
var world = [];
world.height = 10;
world.width = 20;

for (var x = world.width; x--;) {
    for (var y = world.height; y--;) {
        if (!world[x]) world[x] = [];
        world[x][y] = new Tile();
    }
}
```

Your player would also have x/y coordinates.

```
var player = {
    position: { x: 3, y: 5 }
};
```

If you want to find out if an arbitrary location is one of the 8 tiles next to your player:

```
if (player.position.x == x && player.position.y == y) {

    // the tile at x,y is occupied by your player

} else if (Math.abs(player.position.x - x) <= 1 && 
           Math.abs(player.position.y - y) <= 1) {

    // the tile at x,y is next to your player

}
```

If you want to find the 8 tiles next to your player's position:

```
var adjacentTiles = [
    world[player.position.x - 1][player.position.y],
    world[player.position.x + 1][player.position.y],
    world[player.position.x][player.position.y - 1],
    world[player.position.x][player.position.y + 1],
    world[player.position.x - 1][player.position.y - 1],
    world[player.position.x + 1][player.position.y - 1],
    world[player.position.x - 1][player.position.y + 1],
    world[player.position.x + 1][player.position.y + 1]
];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KBLX5/

Comment: I guess this answers your question, but I feel like you probably already knew this. Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: I'm not really with you on how to use the world[], assuming it's an array, I've never seen it with 2 indicies world[x][y].

Also, I kinda need to know what tile the user has pressed, lets say he's on tile 1,1 and presses tile 7,2 I want to be able to record what tile he pressed, how would I do this in a smart way?

Comment: What is up with these: `x--;)`, `y--;)`

Comment: @self it's a condition expression for the `for` statement and an empty final expression (and a right paren).